# Servlet not getting called

Tags: web-applications, servlets

I clearly have the following `Servlet` declared in `web.xml` file under `WEB-INF` folder, but somehow the servlet OnStartup is never called. I use println to trace, there's nothing printed out. Any tips.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>onStartup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.my.package.OnStartup</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Are you sure the Servlet class is in WEB-INF? I'm pedantic and I would think it should be stated as `WEB-INF/classes`, which is the correct location.

Comment: Which menthod did you check ? Trace `init()`

Comment: If you could share the OnStartup Servlet code it will be more helpful..

Comment: @VineetReynolds tks for your reply and valid suggestion. I've checked again, my web.xml is in WEB-INF folder, and so is 'classes' folder. In classes folder, the structure is as I posted, just packages followed by the real class (OnStartup), I can't disclose my real package names but am sure about the correct path.

Comment: @HardikMishra yes, I put println in init()

public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("OnStartup.init() called");
        //my real code here
}

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters, but is there a servlet-mapping as well? I think an absent servlet mapping might be the cause. If not, you should try debugging/tracing the servlet engine of the application server.

Comment: Hi @VineetReynolds, I tried adding a servlet mapping to it as well, no luck. 
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>onStartup</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/onStartup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
Also, I can't call the url directly, does it give any hint where I should look at. About the debugging/tracing the servlet engine, how to do that? tks

Comment: I figured it out. There's a library which I put in OnStartup went missing, which triggered a NoClassDefFound error, which then screwed up the loading process.